How to find the residue of $(2z-1)\cos\left({\frac{z}{z-1}}\right)$ at $z=1$?
How to find the residue at the point $z=1$:$$(2z-1)\cos\left({\frac{z}{z-1}}\right)$$
My attempt:
$$f(z) = \cos(z) \implies f(1) = \cos(1)$$
$$f'(z) = -\sin(z) \implies f'(1) = -\sin(1)$$
$$f''(z) = -\cos(z) \implies f''(1) = -\cos(1)$$
$$f'''(z) = \sin(z) \implies f'''(1) = \sin(1)$$
$$\cos(z) = \cos(1) - \sin(1)(z-1) - \cos(1)\frac{(z-1)^2}{2} + \sin(1)\frac{(z-1)^3}{3!} + \dots$$
$$\cos\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right) = \cos(1) - \sin(1)\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) - \cos(1)\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2} + \sin(1)\frac{1}{3!(z-1)^3} + \dots$$
$$f(z) = (2z-1)\cos\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)$$
Therfore:
$$
\text{Res}(f,1) = -\sin(1)
$$
I have a little doubt whether this solution is right or wrong.

Which step is problematic?

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solution-verification: For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.

You got only half of the solution actually, because you didn't take into account the effect of the factor $2z-1$ on the series expansion. Indeed, given that
$$
\cos\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right) = \cos\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right) = \cos(1)\cos\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) - \sin(1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) 
$$
and $2z-1 = 2(z-1) + 1$, the function
$$
f(z) = (2z-1)\cos\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right) = \left(2(z-1)+1\right) \left(\cos(1)\cos\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) - \sin(1)\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) \right)
$$
is decomposed after distribution into four terms that can be easily expanded around $z = 1$. Two of them, namely the products of the monomial with the sine function and $1$ with the cosine, result in even-powered series and thus cannot contribute to the residue, while the two remaining expansions bring :
$$
[(z-1)^{-1}](z-1)\cos\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) = -\frac{1}{2!}
$$
and
$$
[(z-1)^{-1}]\sin\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right) = 1,
$$
hence
$$
\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}f(z) = 2\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{2}\cos(1)\right) - \sin(1) = -\cos(1)-\sin(1)
$$
in the end.

Another way.
$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=1}f(z) =-\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty}f(z) =\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}\frac1{z^2}f(\frac1z)=\mathrm{Res}_{z=0}\frac{(2-z)\cos(\frac1{1-z})}{z^3}=\frac1{2!}\left((2-z)\cos(\frac1{1-z})\right)''(0)=-(\cos1+\sin1)$$
the second derivative being overkill.
